# How can I eliminate these white outlines on my sprites in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, alpha-blending

I'm recently started working on a game in libgdx, and I've run into the problem that my sprites tend to get a thin, whitish outline around them. This is especially a problem for me since I'm working with ragdolls, so I'm drawing arms as separate sprites from the main torso and ending up with ugly outlines around them. After some googling, I found out this was from the linear filtering I'm doing on my textures. Problem is, linear filtering overall looks much nicer than nearest filtering. After more googling, I found out I should be able to fix this problem with alpha premultiplication. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to go about this in libgdx. Alternatively, if someone knows another way to get rid of the outline, that would be great too. [Here](http://gyazo.com/7c55799a059d59f25d300897062e2a9e) is a screenshot showing what I'm talking about (Images are standins and don't actually belong to me). If you look at the arm, there are clear outlines at the shoulder and elbow.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your game, and links to these pages which you mentioned?

Comment: @ashes999 Not sure where I first read about the filtering issue, but its also covered here [link](http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-966-post-60124.html) where I found out about the premultiplication.